# What is the name of this dictionary?

Tags: python

I want to create dictionary and store information using a function in python.
I wrote the code below.

```
def qwer(num, dictname):
    tmp_inte = 0
    dictname = {}
    print dictname
    while tmp_inte <= num:
        dictname[str(tmp_inte)] = tmp_inte
        tmp_inte += 1
```

If I import this and use it like `qwer(10, "equip")`, what's the name of the newly created dictionary?

If it's name is 'dictname', what should I do to make it work as I want?

Comment: Objects don't actually *have* names. You should just `return` the dict.

Comment: return dictname from function to use it as dictionary for further use

Comment: Dictionaries don't have names.  Neither do lists or sets or any other objects.  You can assign them to variables, and reference them through those variables, but any such variable names are strictly independent of the objects they reference.

Comment: Oh, so I misunderstand about the object.

Comment: It's the same for a (simple) variable (which are also objects anyway): the value `1` doesn't have a name, but if you assign it to a variable, you can reference the value by that variable name: `a = 1` and then later `a`. Python dicts or any other (advanced) types are in that sense no different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dictionary is named `dictname` but only in the scope of the function `qwer` because that is where it is declared as a local variable. The line `dictname = {}` shadows the value of `dictname` that you pass into the function as an argument. Probably what you want to do is return the dictionary from the function and assign this value to `dictname` in the caller:

```
def qwer(num):
    d = {}
    tmp_inte = 0
    while tmp_inte <= num:
        d[str(tmp_inte)] = tmp_inte
        tmp_inte += 1
    return d


dictname = qwer(10)
```

ETA:

Incidentally, increasingly pythonic ways of writing your function would be:

```
def qwer(num):
    d = {}
    for i in range(num+1):
        d[str(i)] = i
    return d
```

And even more so (for python 3.x):

```
def qwer(num):
    return dict([(str(i), i) for i in range(num+1)])
```

or python 2.x:

```
def qwer(num):
    return dict([(str(i), i) for i in xrange(num+1)])
```

Answer (score 4):

If `dictname` is a string that you pass in as an argument, that reference will simply get overwritten when you do `dictname = {}`. The reference to that newly-created dictionary is `dictname`. However, it's immediately thrown away as soon as the function ends. You should `return` it. Then you'll have to save a reference when you call it:

```
def qwer(num):
    tmp_create = 0
    dictname = {}
    print dictname
    while tmp_create <= num:
        dictname[str(tmp_create)] = tmp_create
        tmp_create += 1
    return dictname

equip = qwer(10)
```

Now you have a dictionary with `{'0':0, '1':1,... '10':10}` saved to a reference called `equip`.